# Page redirection and SEO

Tags: seo, hyperlink, redirect

Obviously links from websites with high Page Rank help to position website in terms of SEO. I was wondering if this is also true if the link 'links' to the website that redirects you to your target website? Or will the crawlers ignore the redirection (either by javascript or php?)

```
Scheme:

(1)High PR page links to---->(2)other page that redirects to ---->(3)target page
```

Will the target page in this case benefit from high PR of page (1)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 301 redirect is supposed to pass on most if not all of the page authority. A 302 redirect does not. I would say a direct link is always better than a redirected one, but you probably would be okay with a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously links from websites with high Page Rank help to position website in terms of SEO 
>   no

first of all, pagerank is thoughtcancer. it's bad for you to think about it. said that: it is called page rank, with "page" as in larray page but also like "page" like web page. so you can't get a link from a webSITE with high PAGE rank, but from a web PAGE. and yes if that page has some relevance for what your page is about than this link has a pot. good impact on your performance in search engines for some keywords (but this has nothing to do with pagerank)

second: you are mixing a lot of things together which do not belong together in this fashion, namely crawling and value allocation (which you call pagerank but as i said before: pagerank is thoughtcancer so best not to think about it). ok, if you get a link to your webpage it will probably get crawled, it does not matter if it's via an temp. or perm. redirect. (as long as it's just a few redirects, if it has more than 10 redirects before it reaches the content it probably won't). so crawling is not the issue.

value allocation - every link is a vote for webpage. you can either vote directly (good) or in a permanent HTTP 301 (still good) or temporaray HTTP 302 (propably not what you want) way. to keep it simple, just vote in a direct way. if you have to have some redirects, make sure they are HTTP 301.